# How to use webpack with sequelize?

Tags: sqlite, webpack, sequelize.js

I used webpack+electron+sequelize+sqlite3 in my desktop app, I hope package sequelize into a `bundle.js` by webpack.

I already set externals in webpack.

```
externals: {
        "electron":"require('electron')",
        "sqlite3":"require('sqlite3')"
      },
```

but still get error:

> ERROR in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore' in 'D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres'
>       resolve 'pg-hstore' in 'D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres'
>         Parsed request is a module
>         using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\package.json
>   (relative path: ./lib/dialects/postgres)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\package.json
>   (relative path: ./lib/dialects/postgres)
>           resolve as module
>             D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\nodejs\angular\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\nodejs\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\work\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             looking for modules in D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules
>               using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules)
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               after using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules)
>                 using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules/pg-hstore)
>                   as directory
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore
>   doesn't exist
>                   no extension
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore
>   doesn't exist
>                   .js
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore.js
>   doesn't exist
>                   .ts
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore.ts
>   doesn't exist
>             looking for modules in D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules
>               using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules)
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               after using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules)
>                 using description file: D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules/pg-hstore)
>                   as directory
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore
>   doesn't exist
>                   no extension
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore
>   doesn't exist
>                   .js
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore.js
>   doesn't exist
>                   .ts
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore.ts
>   doesn't exist
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\node_modules]
>       [D:\node_modules]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore.js]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\pg-hstore.ts]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore.js]
>       [D:\work\nodejs\angular\angular2-electron\node_modules\pg-hstore.ts]
>        @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js 3:13-33
>        @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js
>        @ ./~/sequelize/lib/data-types.js
>        @ ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js
>        @ ./~/sequelize/index.js
>        @ ./src/angular/app/data/sequelize/index.ts
>        @ ./src/angular/app/data/sequelize.data.service.ts
>        @ ./src/angular/app/data/data.service.ts
>        @ ./src/angular/app/data/index.ts
>        @ ./src/angular/app/app.module.ts
>        @ ./src/angular/app/main.ts